# Show that modules are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

How can I show whether two modules $ A=\mathbb Z^3/ \langle (2,1,0), (0,-1,0)\rangle$ and $B=\mathbb Z^3/ \langle (1,0,0), (0,1,0)\rangle$ are isomorphic to each other and if they are also free?

Answer (score 0):

> Are they free?

If $A,B$ are $\Bbb Z$-modules, then they are free if you can write $$A\cong\Bbb Z^n\\B\cong\Bbb Z^m$$ for some $m,n\in\Bbb N$.

- $A$. Notice that $\langle (2,1,0), (0,-1,0)\rangle=\langle (2,0,0), (0,1,0)\rangle$, so $$\Bbb Z^3/\langle(2,0,0),(0,1,0)\rangle\cong\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z$$
- $B$. Notice also that with $\langle(1,0,0), (0,1,0)\rangle$ we have $$\Bbb Z^3/\langle(1,0,0), (0,1,0)\rangle\cong\Bbb Z$$

Comment: This is a good reading: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508

Comment: would it mean that N is free but M not?

Comment: @Annalisa I'm not sure what you mean by $M,N$? $B$ is free, since $B\cong\Bbb Z^1$, $A$ is not free.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Totally confused the letters. I am also curious how this $\Bbb Z^3/\langle(2,0,0),(0,1,0)\rangle\cong\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z$ follows.

Answer (score -2):

**Wrong solution, but I don't delete this post so that other people can learn from my mistake.** 
More details about the problems of my solution are mentioned in the comments below.

Start with the following observation: Both subspaces $\langle (2,1,0),(0,-1,0)\rangle$ and $\langle(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\rangle$ are $2$-dimensional and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ (it's okay that the first set only allows even numbers in the first coordinate).

Using this isomorphism we have
$$ A = \mathbb{Z}^3 /\langle (2,1,0),(0,-1,0)\rangle \simeq \mathbb{Z}^3/\mathbb{Z}^2 = \mathbb{Z} \\
B= \mathbb{Z}^3 /\langle (1,0,0),(0,1,0)\rangle \simeq \mathbb{Z}^3/\mathbb{Z}^2 = \mathbb{Z}
$$
and hence $A\simeq B$.

This already shows that both modules are free. Free means that you can represent an $R$-module $M$ as the direct sum of some $R$: $M = \bigoplus_{e\in E} R$, where $E$ is the basis. Here the direct sum consists of just one copy of $\mathbb{Z}$.

But you can give a direct isomorphism as well:
$\phi:B\to A, (0,0,x) \mapsto (1,0,\frac{x}{2})$ if $x$ is even and $(0,0,x)\mapsto (0,0,\frac{x+1}{2})$ if $x$ is odd.

$\phi$ is a bijective function. But I'm not sure if this bijective function is an isomorphism as well because of the $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ I omitted. Maybe someone can clarify this.

Comment: dear LegNaiB, the issue is that you are implicitly assuming the following: if $M$ is a module and $N_1,N_2\leqslant M$ are submodules such that $N_1\cong N_2$, then $M/N_1\cong M/N_2$. this is *not* true in general. for a more tractable example, suppose $M=\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\times\cdots$ (infinitely many times) and $N_1=M$ and $N_2=0\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\times\cdots$. then $N_1\cong N_2$, since both are an infinite direct power of $\mathbb{N}$ (can you come up with an isomorphism?). but $M/N_1=0$ and $M/N_2\cong\mathbb{Z}$, so the quotients are not isomorphic

Comment: there are cases in which it *can* be true, however: for example, if there is an automorphism $f:M\to M$ such that $f(N_1)=N_2$, then can you see why $f$ induces an isomorphism $M/N_1\cong M/N_2$? but it will not be true in general

Comment: (in fact, for an even simpler example of the one I gave, suppose $M=\mathbb{Z}$ and $N_1=\mathbb{Z}$ and $N_2=2\mathbb{Z}$. as you note in your answer, we have $N_1\cong N_2$. but is $M/N_1$ isomorphic to $M/N_2$?)

Comment: Thanks for clarification. In your example there is no isomorphism as we have one element in the one set and two in the other set. Your other example yields such an isomorphism using the homomorphie theorem for $f$ to $M/N_2$. But how about the bijection I gave in $\Phi$? Is it because the structure of addition is not preserved?

Comment: dear LegNaiB, there are a few problems with your map $\phi$. for one thing, note that $x=0$ is even, so we have $\phi(0,0,0)=(1,0,0)$, and thus $\phi$ is not a homomorphism. (recall that a homomorphism must map $0$ to $0$.) more generally, yes, your map is not additive: note, if $x$ is odd, then $2\phi(0,0,x)$ equals $(0,0,x+1)$, but $\phi(0,0,2x)=(1,0,x)$. these two are not equal

Comment: @Atticus, thanks for your patience and the clarification

Comment: Should I delete this answer as it's wrong?

Comment: dear LegNaiB, my pleasure, happy it helped!! :) ... as for deletion I have no opinion, I think it is up to you!

Comment: I will leave it there. I clearly added that the answer is wrong, but maybe some other person can use this discussion to avoid making such a mistake like I did